# how to make a child DIV's width wider than the parent DIV using position styles

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me?

My code below is not working in responsive mode.

Parent container placement should be at the right side of the screen.

*Here's my code*

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid red;
  height:200px;

}    
.child {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:-100px;
  right:-100px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Need width 100% by screen resolution</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm added an answer ,if it's useful don't forget to tick :P

Answer (score 1):

```
.child {
  position:absolute;
  width:150%;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

You don't need to have left and right values when you have width, unless you want to specify the position.

A left:0; means that the leftmost part of the div is at the leftmost part of its parent div while a right:0; means that the rightmost part of the div is at the rightmost part of its parent div- this could act as a replacement for the width as

```
left:0; 
right:0;
```

is similar to

```
left:0;
width:100%;
```

With this, you could specify a

```
left:0;
right:-10%;
```

and it would be equivalent to a

```
left:0;
width:110%;
```

P.S. you could also use VW and VH instead of %. 
A 100% refers to the full size of the parent while a 100vw refers to the full width of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```css
html,body{
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
.main{
  width:980px; background:darkGreen; margin:0 auto;
}
.rel{
  width:400px; height:200px; background:#000; margin:0 auto; position:relative;
}
.abs{
  width:550px; height:100px; background:yellow; position:absolute; left:-75px; top:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div class='rel'><div class='abs'></div></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **`position:relative`** from parent and in your code you forget one **semi colon** (;) after right property of your **.child**.it,s important to put a semi colon after every property in css.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
.parent {
  /*position:relative;*/
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid red;
height:200px;

}    
.child {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  left:-100px;
  right:-100px;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Need width 100% by screen resolution</p>
  </div>
</div>
```